# How to optimize a query in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, optimization, postgresql-performance

I have three tables: company, employments and entries. A company has many employments and a single employment has many entries.

The entries table has the most items in the entire database (currently 52M items) and it has a columns called `deleted_by_user`.

I have an index for employment.id in the entries table.
I have an index for company.id in the employments table.

The query i am currently having issues with is the following:

```
SELECT
    entries.*
FROM entries
INNER JOIN 
    employments
ON entries.employment_id = employments.id
WHERE employments.company_id = X
AND entries.deleted_by_user = TRUE
```

Is there a way to rewrite this query or the solution is to get a better hardware?

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions). Also, are you considering options other than _rewrite this query or [...] get a better hardware_? Some more indexes, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like you need a fast nested loop join. The best indexes for that would be

```
CREATE INDEX emp_comp_id_idx ON employments (company_id);
CREATE INDEX ent_emp_id_idx ON entries (employment_id);
```

You can speed this up considerably if you cluster `entries` along that index:

```
CLUSTER entries USING ent_emp_id_idx;
```

But beware: that last statement will rewrite the table and lock it to all concurrent access until the rewrite is done, so you need down time. Also, the order is not maintained, and you have to run `CLUSTER` again when the performance starts to deteriorate.

If you only needed a few columns from `entries`, there would also be the option of an index-only scan, which would boost performance even more.